# Get the first element from var_dump($_POST) array

Tags: php, arrays

This is the output I get when I used

```
var_dump($_POST) array(6) {
    ["merchant_id"]=> string(6) "sam" 
    ["passkey"]=> string(4) "1234" 
    ["amt"]=> string(5) "10.00" 
    ["email"]=> string(16) "sam@gmail.com"
    ["mobileNo"]=> string(10) "9874563210" 
    ["orderID"]=> string(6) "123456"
}
```

My question is , how can I get the first element in this array,or the first element which is populated in `$_POST` global varablie?

i have tried

```
var_dump($_POST[0])
```

or

```
var_dump($_POST)[0]
```

but nothing seems working.I want to get "merchant_id",not its value

**EDIT**

AS AN IDEAL CONDITION I DONT KNOW WHATS THE FIRST ELEMENT IS,I WANT TO CHECK IF

```
if (FIRST ELEMENT OF $_POST == 'merchant_id') {
....
}
if (first element of $_POST == 'orderID') {
...
}
```

this is what Im trying to achieve.How to  get the variable name of first element of $_POST?

Comment: How do you determine the "first" element of a hash?

Comment: Try `$yourfirstvar=array_shift($_POST);`

Comment: an associative array doesn't have an index. it has keys.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran Your answer is right,but IM getting the value of the first element but not the variable,as inmy question "merchant_id" I need to get

Comment: Try `var_dump($yourfirstvar)` , investigate and `echo` as per your needs.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST['merchant_id'])`

Comment: he wants to get associative index

Comment: Why do you want to rely on order of elements in an associative array (which is unordered by definition)? It's a sign you're doing something terribly wrong

Comment: updated the question,please check

Comment: @user34305: why do you need that? Your whole design looks broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `[0]` but there is no key in your array as its an *associative array*, so define the index name instead

```
echo $_POST['merchant_id'];
```

---

As commented, if you want to `echo` the *key* than you can `reset` and use `key()`

```
reset($_POST); //reset it first
$key = key($_POST);
```

Comment: It is `$_POST` and not `$POST`

Comment: OP wants "to get "merchant_id",not its value"

Comment: see,I 'merchant_id' is suppose to be an unknown vairiable.It may change.So that is why I wanted to know whats the variable name of the first element in the $_POST array

Comment: BTW...I don't understand why this answer has been upvoted twice...
You should pass an extra parameter, like $_POST["key"]="merchant_id"

Comment: @Antoine also contributed a solution for that

Comment: That was an edit...and you got the upvotes for the original post, which was completely wrong

Comment: @Antoine but anyways I contributed the solution, so what's the problem? answer isn't wrong

Comment: @Antoine: even though the original question and the solution OP is finding is stupid - this answer does answer it.

Comment: @zerkms how can u say it to be stupid.If you cant answer it doesnt mean its stupid!

Comment: @zerkms and I get a downvote... if you see any of my php answers, some or the other downvotes for no good reason...

Comment: @user34305 see the dude's profile and than you should comment that haha

Comment: You can say whatever you want, the fact is you have been upvoted twice for a wrong answer, so I think the downvote is justified

Comment: @user34305: I can answer, but the design you've chosen is fragile. If you explained the original task we could help you with a real solution, not a workaround

Comment: @Antoine I don't mind if you downvote, perhaps you should learn the sites rules, people who downvote takes back if the answers are edited, I answered correctly, but downvoting after the correct answer IS NOT JUSTIFIED

Comment: @Mr. Alien: yep, that's what confuses me as well

Comment: @Zerkms every question has its own way of thinking.If you call it,its just an excuse that you cannot answer it like Mr Alien and all others have tried with their best knowledge.And thanks to Mr.Alien Antoine Muhammet for helping

Comment: @user34305: if you don't mind that the design you've chosen is stupid - fine, good luck with it

Comment: This question was helpfull @Mr.Alien,and he has edited it to match what I asked..And Thanks!

Comment: @Antoine: he provided the correct answer for the initial question. OP **DID NOT** mention they need a key, not a value. So as soon as Mr. Alien cannot read minds - it was 100% correct answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not, you are, for your points. You ask for explainations, I'm just explaining what I did & why.

Comment: @zerkms ya,im sorry for that,thats why editted the question again

Comment: @Antoine: so you're wrong. You've downvoted a correct answer. If OP doesn't know the correct terms and misuse the terms - then **IT IS NOT** the answerers' issue.

Comment: Question was perfectly clear for me and others people who answered apparently

Comment: @Mr.Alien But I dont know whats the correct format of what Im trying to do,since zerkms says this is not the correct way to do what im trying to achieve,Im trying to get the first element in the post variable and check it with an if statement,if it has this merchant_id.any better way to do that?

Comment: @zerkms Will this array be unordered always?Gets shuffled and not possible to get first element?

Comment: @user34305: associative array is an unordered structure. Even though currently it preserves the order, it doesn't mean that client wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Antoine see the 4th edit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20797442/revisions), -user, your construct seems to be incorrect, I see no reason for doing that...

Comment: Oh so if I want to search if 'mechant_id' keys exists in $_POST what can be the solution for that

Comment: @user34305 At some point you will need to rewrite this code because what you have is simply maintainable at this point. I guess you want to google either _front controller_ or _dispatcher/router_. Also read up on `switch` (referring to last part of your question).

Answer (score 5):

I think he wants associative key rather than the value

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
echo $keys[0]; // prints merchant_id
```

Comment: he is asking for index name